# Azure devops Yaml :how to set for loop over agent pool name

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml

I have a use case to run the same stage on different Azure pool name, looking to have a logic to iterate over the pool name

Is there something like this which can work ?

```
stages:
- ${{ each name in parameters.poolNames }}:
 - stage: Stage1
   jobs:
   - job: Job1
     pool:
       name: ${{parameters.poolNames}}
     steps:
     - script: echo Hello, world!
       displayName: "Run echo hello world ${{parameters.regionName}} ${{parameters.poolName}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the matrix strategy. Have a look at [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started-multiplatform?view=azure-devops), you should be able to adapt it your use case.

Comment: your suggestion worked for me but it took me some time to understand it completely. Thanks though! :)

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
parameters:
- name: environment
 displayName: 'List of Environments'
 type: object
 default:
    - prod
    - clientpp
    - uat
stages:
- stage: Generate_reports
 jobs:
    - ${{ each environment in parameters.environment }}:
      - job: Generating_reports_${{ environment }}
        pool:
           name: ${{ environment }}
       steps:
          - script: |
             #!/bin/bash
              bin/reports.sh ${{ environment }}
```